# Database normalisation - some issues

Tags: sql, database, database-design, normalization

I am completing some work for Uni and have a single table of data that i need to arrange into 1st,2nd and 3rd Normal Form, i have attempted to do so below but i have hit a brick wall with it.

I would appreciate any helpful input at all as my tutor is away on holiday and I don't want to start the rest of the work using the wrong tables/relations to start with.

Basically the system is supposed to allow users to add films, directors and actors. Allow multiple users to review films and categorise the films by genre.

#### UNF

```
**filmID**
title
directorID
categoryID
categoryName
notes
directorName
actorName
actorID
role
userID
userName
reviewDate
reviewText
```

#### 1NF

```
**filmID**
title
notes

**directorID**
directorName

**categoryID**
categoryName

**actorID
filmID***
actorName
role

**userID**
userName

**filmID*
userID***
reviewDate
reviewText
```

#### 2NF

```
**filmID**
title
notes

**directorID**
directorName

**categoryID**
categoryName

**actorID**
actorName

**actorID
filmID***
role

**userID**
userName

**filmID*
userID***
reviewDate
reviewText
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, share, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: You appear to be missing some way to tie directors and categories/genres to films.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find here on Stack Overflow that people won't answer your homework for you.

However here's a link to a very good tutorial.

[Normalisation Tutorial](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)

You'll understand it much better if you work through it and complete it yourself, rather than copying and pasting the answer from here.

Comment: Believe me this is only the tip of the iceberg, i have to code a dynamic php website to display the information from the tables and i am not the best with php at all.

I have already organised the data into what i think s 2NF and am simply asking if this is correct before i go on. I can't seem to figure out what the next step is for 3NF.

I didn't ask for people to be condescending, just for some advice.

Thanks

Comment: And my advice is to do the tutorial and learn it properly. You say yourself this is only the beginning, so why not make sure you know the basics inside out to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some questions for you...

- Can an actor also be a director?
- Can a film have more than one director?
- Can a user review a film more than once?
- Are the genres predefined?
- Can an actor play more than one role in a film?

Comment: An Actor cannot be a director.
A film can have only one Director.
A user can review more than one film at once.
Genres are predefined.
An Actor can only play one role in a film.

Comment: Perhaps @podiluska's first question should have been Can an actor never be a director? Given you are discounting those films where an actor plays more than one role, (no greate loss) or act and directs. No Reservoir Dogs??? Can an actor or a director review a film? Clue how many different tables are you going to have to put Quentin in?

Comment: And does your data structure meet those requirements? No Woody Allen, then, nor Coen Brothers, nor Austin Powers? Where is the list of genres?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: "Given you are discounting those films where an actor plays more than one role, (no greate loss)" . . . Peter Sellers's three roles in *Dr. Strangelove*? HUGE loss!

Comment: @Catcall, it's not all bad. Those awful Eddie Murphy films for instance

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that a database that meets the criteria for 2nd Normal Form also meets the criteria for 3rd Normal Form.  It looks like that is the case here.